# How to get line on iMac from file/etc/profile in red color, when login as root

Tags: bash

I have assignment on iMac /etc/profile add the line below

```
RED='\033[0;31m'    
if [ $USER == "root" ]; then    
    echo \x1B "\033Danger!! root is doing stuff in \w[0;31m"    
fi
```

I am supposed to get this line in  red color, when login as root, but I don't have anything. Should I do it in different way or in another file?

Comment: You use `\w` in the output; is this supposed to appear in a prompt?

Comment: This is going to be very annoying.  Don't put interactive stuff in files which are executed by automation tasks as well.

Answer (score 1):

To get the color red you need to use:

```
printf '%b' "\033[31;1mDanger\033[0m\n"
```

This should work:

```
if [ "$USER" = "root" ]; then 
    printf '%b' "\033[31;1mDanger! root is doing stuff in\033[0m\n"
fi
```

Thanks to Chepner for the information and helping to make this answer POSIX compliant.

Comment: Don't put `bash`-specific syntax in `/etc/profile`, though.

Comment: Perfectly works. Where can I find the table of colors for baSH?

Comment: @chepner perhaps you could post an answer to explain why using bash specific syntax in `/etc/profile` is a bad idea.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is used by shells other than `bash`, shells that will not understand `$'...'` and will simply exit with an error when encountering it.

Comment: @chepner So in the context of this question do you consider this to be an incorrect answer?

Comment: Yes: you are advocating putting non-POSIX-compliant code in a POSIX shell configuration file.

Comment: @chepner After searching the internet for "POSIX compliant color code" and "POSIX compliant code" I am still uncertain as to what the correct answer in this case would be. Is `printf '%b' "\033[31;1mDanger\033[0m\n"` POSIX compliant? And if not, can you point me in the right direction? The whole question of what is and is not POSIX compliant is something I am struggling to understand.

Comment: That is correct. The `$'...'` quoting mechanism is the `bash` extension. (`echo` is technically part of POSIX, but is best avoided because the standard doesn't forbid a lot of conflicting implementations.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the information. I have updated the answer to hopefully be POSIX compliant.

Comment: Sorry, in which file can I put this line then?

Comment: @osamuyl My previous answer, though it worked for displaying colors, was not something that should be used in `/etc/profile`. However, the current answer is safe to use.